# Send data to azure event hub using python app

Tags: python, azure, message-queue, azure-eventhub

I'm sending a JSON dump to the event hub using my python app.
My connection string is of the form

> connection_string="Endpoint=sb://xyz.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=abc;SharedAccessKey=pqr"

I get the following response

> Token put complete with result: 0, status: 202, description: b'Accepted', connection:xxxxxxxxx

But I don't see the data in the eventhub. I don't get any error as well. My question is the event being sent? If the event is successfully sent, should we not get a response code 200?

My code is from this [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhub/samples/sync_samples/send.py)

```
from azure.eventhub import EventHubProducerClient, EventData

def send_event_data_batch(producer, data):
    # Without specifying partition_id or partition_key
    # the events will be distributed to available partitions via round-robin.
    event_data_batch = producer.create_batch()
    event_data_batch.add(EventData(data))
    try:
        producer.send_batch(event_data_batch)
    except Exception as exp:
        _LOG.info(type(exp).__name__)
        _LOG.info(exp.args)
    producer.close()


def send_data_to_event_hub(data):
    producer = EventHubProducerClient.from_connection_string(
        conn_str=connection_string,
        eventhub_name="EVENT HUB NAME" )
    with producer:
        send_event_data_batch(producer, data)
    producer.close()
```

Comment: How do you check the data is not in eventhub? and also let us know which version of sdk you're using.

Comment: Where do you get the response in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The send() method returns nothing (`None`) if it's successful, or raises an error of family `EventHubError` if it's not successful.
The "Token put complete with result: 0, status: 202, description: b'Accepted', connection:xxxxxxxxx" is logging information of building connections.